# Tweetbot for Mac like snapping windows

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, snapping

I am trying to reproduce the windows snapping/merge functionnality of the last Tweetbot for Mac.
If you have 2 windows and you bring one close to the other, they snap and are merge in a single window.

Do you know how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indragie Karunaratne (@Indragie) created an NSWindow subclass to do just that.

https://github.com/indragiek/INDockableWindow